# i need to allow the data which is in between the start and end date

Tags: c#, sql

Here i given my database table. i need to create a code to allow the data to show after the start date and remove the data after the end date:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: Do you have any C# or SQL code to show?

Comment: currently i create the table only ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column1,column2 From table_name where start_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date AND end_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

Comment: the table had separate columns for start and end date

Comment: this is logically right... but it could't work .... give some diff code

Comment: `StartDate' will always be between itself and another value, same with `EndDate`. Might as well just skip the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

To remove date when `End` occurs you can use the `DELETE` command and use the internal date (`GetDate()` in Sql Server) as a reference. Then do a `SELECT` to get the records for the current offers, again using the internal date. Both commands can be used together, just separate with a semicolon

```
DELETE FROM [Table] WHERE GetDate() >= [End];
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE GetDate() >= [Start];
```

If you would like this to be a Stored Procedure, it is fairly simple to do. All you need to do is to wrap those commands with a `CREATE PROCEDURE` block. The hardest thing about it coming up with a name.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.mp_GetCurrentOffers 
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM [Table] WHERE GetDate() >= [End];
    SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE GetDate() >= [Start];
END
GO
```

Comment: can you please create a stored procedure for the process

Comment: Rather trivial to convert, but added that in to my answer

Answer (score 0):

SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ProductTable a,OfferTable b where a.Product_ID='" + textBox15.Text + "' and b.start_date<=(GETDATE())", con);

this code is used to show the data after the start date....

thanks to all who tried to help me .

Answer (score -1):

here i found a technique to solve the deletion process but i need to hide the data which is not satisfied the condition .... plese go through this link to see the code which i was used.

Screenshot:

[image]